# QTextEdit large file support

Tags: qt

[QTableView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtableview.html) and [QTreeView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtreeview.html) both have a [setModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtreeview.html#setModel) method which allows you to implement a data provider for the widget, but [QTextEdit](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtextedit.html) has no such method.

How would I go about implementing a sliding window view onto a text document that allows me to manage the data backing the widget?

Comment: What is "large file", how large? QTextEdit is not made for splitting its lines into a model. Do you need to edit the data or is it read-only?

Comment: I don't see how giving you numbers will clarify the question. I'm looking for a way to implement model-view-controller or model-view-delegate on a QTextEdit.

Comment: Because you are trying to abuse a component for something it is not made for. So if you want people to help you hacking, you need to provide more information.

Comment: You can consider the file to be infinite in size. I want to show the user a window onto the data, and have them be able to manipulate and select text. This does not necessarily need to be a QTextEdit, but a QTable or QTree will not suffice.

Comment: I have too looked into this, but sadly there is hardwired assumption that all the text is in memory and the number of blocks is known. So you have to manage the window yourself, by appending/prepending blocks on one end and removing them on the other end as user moves around. I hope this is clearer explanation than allegations of "component abuse".